# Underscored field to uppercase with gson

Tags: java, gson

I want to map underscored field name in json to uppercase with Gson.

for example,

`{"item" : "hello", "this_field_to_mapped":1}`

to

```
public class MyItem{
 private String item;
 private int thisFieldToMapped; // this from this_field_to_mapped
}
```

I've created Gson object using builder but this field value is 0.

```
private class UnderScoreToUpper implements FieldNamingStrategy{

    @Override
    public String translateName(Field f) {

        String name = f.getName();

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[_][a-z]{1}");

        Matcher m = p.matcher(name);

        while(m.find()){
            System.out.println("matched : " + m.group(0));
            String c = m.group(0).replace("_", "").toUpperCase();
            name = name.replace(m.group(0), c);
        }

        System.out.println("replaced : " + name);

        return name;
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T query(Type typeOfT) {

    Gson g = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
            .setFieldNamingStrategy(new UnderScoreToUpper())
            .serializeSpecialFloatingPointValues()
            .setPrettyPrinting()
            .serializeNulls().create();

    String jsonString = this.query();
    T res = (T) g.fromJson(jsonString, typeOfT);

    return res;
}
```

I've tried another practice that was adding `@SerializedName`.

```
public class MyItem{
 private String item;
 @Serializedname("this_field_to_mapped") private int thisFieldToMapped; // this from this_field_to_mapped
}
```

However, I want to map these without adding `@serializedName` each fields.

What is best practice for automation ?

Comment: So you have created this `UnderScoreToUpper` strategy, and… what? What happened? How did it fail to work as intended? Have you added debug output, to see whether it gets called, what its input is, and what its output?

Comment: @MvG in first case, item field is fine, but thisFieldToMapped is 0, I can use a second case but I don't want use `@Serializedname` annotation because I have many Json objects and need to parse underscored attributes.